# How does asp.net MVC maintain a control's state if it doesn't support viewstate ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, webforms

I have been working in c# web forms for the last 4 years and now moving to MVC.

I have been watching tutorials and keep on hearing these 2 things.

1) MVC doesn't store controls state such as textboxes' data etc.
2) It does not postback.

Ok, fine but I have 2 questions regarding the points given above.

1. If it doesn't store controls state using view state then how it does? How would one maintain the text of selected value inside a control after submitted data to the server?
2. If it doesn't post back then how does controller submit the data to the server and returns the result?

Thanks.

Comment: Through models if the vie is bound to a model else it doesnt

Comment: There are no "controls" in MVC. There are just plain old HTML elements.

Comment: @Jamiec and what about the postback? it still submits the data whether it is via ajax or anything.

Comment: "postback" is a very webforms concept. MVC Just uses plain old HTML form posts to submit data to the server - or you can implement your own (or one of the many library) AJAX methods of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are still confused by some of the concepts of MVC, and how they differ (quite substantially) from WebForms. The best remedy to this is just to try it out, use some of the standard simple templates provided for you.

In answer to your questions

> If it doesn't store controls state using view state then how it does? How would one maintain the text of selected value inside a control after submitted data to the server?

MVC uses plain HTML elements. It is up to the developer to bind the values they require to these elements. If you are submitting data via ajax, there is no need to do anything - the user will not have moved off the page so any values will still be present. If submitting by form post, and returning the user to the same view afterwards, you would include the submitted value as part of the model and re-bind the value.

> If it doesn't post back then how does controller submit the data to the server and returns the result?

As mentioned above, you can submit data by writing some javascript to do an ajax request with the contents of the form, or using a HTML form post. Results are returned by including a new model in the response from a controller method.